# Call a Django view from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, django

Say I'm writing a web app, web shop to sell antique coins, and I have an HTML combobox (`<select>`) and upon selection (say, I selected 'gold' to list only golden coins) I want to redirect to a specific Django view, how can I do that? My guess is JavaScript, but I'm not sure how to properly construct a URL to the desired Django view.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
var combobox = document.getElementById('category-combobox');
combobox.addEventListener('change', spam);
​
function spam() {
    window.location.replace("/shop/search/?q=" + combobox.value);
}
```

I'm just wonderring if there's a better way than manually harcoding URLs

Comment: Just like any other URL. Where are you having problems?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not sure how to properly construct it, i.e. I would have to manually hardcode it.

Comment: As opposed to what? Please show some code.

Comment: you need a url where you expect to get a pk, for the type of thing the user selected. Those should be records of one relation, and the select would include the label and the pk as a value, like 
<select>
    <option value="1">Gold coins</option>
</select>
The select would need a change listener and then redirect the user to a predefined url, adding the pk.
Remember you can form the url starting with a / so you don't have to specify a domain name, and the url will point to the same domain where that link was created.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added some code. So I'm looking for something like `reverse()` but from within JavaScript, if that makes sense.

Comment: I believe @DanielRoseman is stating that you can easily use the `{% url 'url_name' %}` url tag in your template when calling a URL in JS. If it is pure JS, simply place it in script tags inside an HTML page.

Comment: @ViaTech it's not possible to do that because my template and my JS are two separate files

Comment: That is fine @dedmauz69, you can put your JS in an HTML file and naturally wrap it in script tags, then just call `{% include 'js.html' %}` and it is inside your page as you'd expect... If you can't do that, then yes you are correct, you are unable to use the url template tags inside of pure .js files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use [django-js-reverse](https://github.com/ierror/django-js-reverse).

Step 1: install it with `pip`

```
pip install django-js-reverse
```

Step 2: add `'django_js_reverse'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_js_reverse',
]
```

Step 3: `urls.py`

```
from django_js_reverse.views import urls_js

urlpatterns = [
    path('jsreverse/', urls_js, name='js_reverse'),
]
```

Step 4: include `js_reverse` in your template

```
<script src="{% url 'js_reverse' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Step 5: use your views from JavaScript

```
Urls['products:products-list']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jinja logic to define a URL you want to redirect to using the script tag in your template you're rendering. Then in your JS you can catch the state change of select box, get it's value store it in a variable called `params`, and append the appropriate `?` to signify `url parameter` and then redirect to that page. I hope you get what I am saying.

file.html

```
<select id="category">
    <option value="gold">Gold</option>
    <option value="silver">Silver</option>
</select>
<script>
    var PAGE_URL = "{% url 'appname:urlname' %}"
</script>
<script src="file.js" type="text/js"></script>
```

file.js

```
$("#category").on('change', function(){
    params = "?search="+this.val;
    window.locaiton.replace(PAGE_URL+params);
});
```